# TYPO3 : set title attribute to link of pages

Tags: typo3

I'm working on the accessibility of my project, in particular by adding "title" attributes to the internal links of my pages,
For example, I've created a menu and I'd like to add "title" attributes.

I've tried to edit one of my pages and complete the following fields:
[title] [nav_title]

but it doesn't display the title when I move my mouse over the link

Could someone tell me how to add this attribute to the links on my pages?

Thanks

Comment: Please share some code. `link.typolink`-viewhelper has a title-parameter. And the same counts for the TypoScript way via `typolink`.

Comment: what version of TYPO3? how did you create your menu? (TypoScript/ FLUID/ ...) if you want additional attributes you need to provide these attributes when the link is generated. ATM additional fields are not used by default for all links.

Comment: Are you sure you need a title attribute for accessibility?

"The purpose of each link can be determined from the link text alone or from the link text together with its programmatically determined link context, except where the purpose of the link would be ambiguous to users in general."
https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/link-purpose-in-context.html